# How to fetch line numbers for all 'if' 'else' and 'elif' positions in a python file

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Example: Suppose, we have a .py file containing the below code snippet. How do we read and extract the positions of if-elif-else

```
If fisrtconditon:#line 1
    If sub-condition:#line2
       print(line no 3)
elif secnd_condn:#line 4
     Xyz..#line5
     Xyz..#line6
elif third condition:line7
     ...line 8
else:#line 9
    Some content #line10***
```

Output:

```
[1,4,7,9]
```

Comment: What would you do with `[i if i%3==1 else 0 for i in range(10) if i%2 ==0]`,

Comment: And if the code contains a line such as, for example, `open('music.riff') as f:`, which also contains `if`, should this be included, or do you only want to include real Python `if` statements?

Comment: @Aloy Did my answer meet your exact requirements? Please see the assumptions I have made. If not, can you please unaccept my answer so I may delete it (I am unable to delete an answer that was accepted). Also, if they do not meet your exact requirements, please update your question to give more specifications.

Comment: @oda The answer perfectly met all requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to iterate over the lines of the file, using `enumerate` to help you get the line number:

```
with open("somefile.py") as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f, start = 1):
        if line[:2] ==  "if" and (line[2].isspace() or line[2] == "("):
            print(line_no, "if")
        elif line[:4] == "elif" and (line[4].isspace() or line[4] == "("):
            print(line_no, "elif")
        elif line[:4] == "else" and (line[4].isspace() or line[4] == ":"):
            print(line_no, "else")
```

**Assumptions**: this program assumes that `somefile.py` has correct syntax. Moreover, if this `if` statement appears indented, for example, inside a function definition, it would not work. The question's specifications did not dictate this requirement.

This program

- opens the file `"somefile.py"` for reading (the default mode of `open`);
- iterates over the lines of the file, using `enumerate` to get an index; by default, indices will start from `0` but we specify the `start` parameter so that it starts from `1`;
- if the line starts with an `if` plus a (whitespace character or opening paren) or an `elif` plus a (whitespace character or opening paren) or an `else` plus a (colon `:` or a whitespace character), then we print the line number as well as the corresponding `if`, `elif`, or `else`.
- as we exit the `with` block, Python closes the file for us.

**Example**

---

If `somefile.py` is

```
if condition:
    if condition:
        something
elif condition:
    something
    something
elif condition:
    something
else:
    something
```

then the above program outputs

```
1 if
4 elif
7 elif
9 else
```

Comment: @wovano Exactly. This fix covers what you first mentioned. I have realized that this is actually more complicated. I think I will delete my answer.

Comment: @wovano By the way, OP said that line 2 should not be included in the output (OP deleted the comment that said that). I also think OP wants real Python `if`s.

Comment: Questions that are not clear should indeed not be answered for exactly this reason. There are now several answers that will only work under specific assumptions. Since the question is tagged with "abstract-syntax-tree" I think it's a fairly invalid assumption that indented code should not be taken into account (otherwise it has _nothing_ to do with AST and it's just a simple pattern match with unclear requirements). And the reason for excluding line 2 is unknown since that information is not included in the question.

Comment: @wovano. By this AST-tag logic the second line should be included but the OP explicitly said that it should not. The problem is that the question specifications are not clear enough. Hence assumptions do need to be made. The answer that uses ast does not give OP's expected output (it says there is an if at line 2 when the output in the question explicitly does not include one).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `ast` module.

```py
import ast

with open('file.py') as f:
    tree = ast.parse(f.read())  # parse the file

for node in ast.walk(tree):  # walk the tree
    if isinstance(node, ast.If):  # if the node is an If (or an If-else)
        print('If at line', node.lineno)  # print the line number
        if node.orelse:  # if the node has an else
            if isinstance(node.orelse[0], ast.If):  # if the else is an If
                print('Elif at line', node.orelse[0].lineno)  # print the line number
            else:
                print('Else at line', node.orelse[0].lineno)  # print the line number
```

ast is part of the standard library, so there's no need to install anything. It stands for Abstract Syntax Tree, and it's a representation of the structure of your code. You can find more information in the [ast module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

Comment: Perhaps you can show the output of executing this code with an `if` statement identical to OP's? For example, replace all conditions by 5 and all nested statements with a `pass`. Your code is showing that there is an `if` at lines 1, 2, 4, 7, `elif` at lines 4, 7, and `else` at line 10 where output in the post says to only pick out lines 1, 4, 7, 9.

Answer (score 0):

one-liner:

```
indexes = [x+1 for x in range(len(content)) if any(x in ['if', 'elif', 'else'] for x in [list(content[x].lower().replace('#line',' ').replace(':',' ').split(' '))[0]])]
```

indexes:

```
[1, 4, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

The snipped below should do it :)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# get_lines.py

def get_lines():
    lines = []
    with open('file.py') as f:
        f = f.readlines()
    for line in range(len(f)):
        if f[line].startswith(('if', 'elif', 'else')):
            lines.append(line + 1)
    return lines


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_lines())
```